# Renewal of Canadian Visa

Tags: visas

My Canadian Tourist Visa expires in Nov 2018. So how do I renew the same? Is a fresh Application still required or is there a simpler way?

Comment: What do you need to know that isn't on the Canadian government's website, or the website of the Canadian embassy in your country?

Comment: First edit your question and add whether you are inside Canada or outside of Canada currently.

Answer (score 1):

I presume you are talking about a six month tourist visa, if so you can apply to extend your current visitor visa for you to stay, this must be done 30 days before it expires.

The Canadian Government's website allows you to do this online [here](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/visit-canada/extend-stay/apply.html) as well as documents other options.